# IlvText vs IlvLabel position and text size

Tags: ilog

I'm trying to create a multi line text on the screen, using ILog JViews.

I started with using `IlvLabel` , which put the text in the position I want (Using the constructor which get a point and a string for the text). I then saw the label does not support multi lines. 
I then tried switching to `IlvText` which does support multi line, but using it created a very huge text (using same constructor of point and text). I then tried using the `resize` method to make it smaller which did make it smaller but then the text appeared in a different place than where the `IlvLabel` would appear.

What is the difference between the points in the 2 constructors and how do I make the text appear in the same position for the `IlvText` as the `IlvLabel` would appear?